# Error executing sql script with hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

I use h2 db and hibernate 4.

I want to autogenerate db schema from entities and fill in db from `import.sql` file . Here is relevant `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<!-- automatically generate database tables from hibernate entities -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <!-- initialize db on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/import.sql</property>
```

So when database tables are generated `import.sql` is called. Here is the first sql statement:

```
insert into Borrower values (1,"Greece, Aphines, Square street",5,"Antonio");
```

When hibernate runs this sql statement it gives an error:

```
    квіт 23, 2015 8:56:43 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport importScript
    ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: insert into Borrower values (1,"Greece, Aphines, Square street",5,"Antonio")
    квіт 23, 2015 8:56:43 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport importScript
    Column "Greece, Aphines, Square street" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Borrower values (1,"Greece, Aphines, Square street",5,"Antonio") [42122-186]
```

Adding column names inside `insert into` statement doesn't help.

This seems to be error of h2 database.

What means this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with replace doulbe quote by single quote as below:

```
insert into Borrower values (1,'Greece, Aphines, Square street',5,'Antonio');
```

Comment: What does double quote mean in h2?

Comment: I also found that getting rid of MySQL's backquotes ( ` ) made it work too.